# Accesing Private variables from a parent class - JAVA

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I haven't included the main function since it's empty.I am trying to access the private variable **name** from my parent class to the child class but then it throws an error message.It would be nice if you could help me out.I am new to JAVA btw.

```
public class Author {
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private char gender;
        public Author(String name,String email,char gender)
        {
            this.name=name;
            this.email=email;
            this.gender=gender;         
        }
        protected String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        //protected String 

    }
    public class Book extends Author {
        private String name;
        private String authorname;
        private double price;
        private int qtyInStock;
        Book(String name,Author a,double price,int qtyInStock)
        {
            this.name=name;
            this.authorname=a.getName(); //Error
            this.price=price;
            this.qtyInStock=qtyInStock;
        }

    }
```

Error Message:

> Implicit super constructor HelloWorld.Author() is undefined. Must
>   explicitly invoke another constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Implicit super constructor HelloWorld.Author() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor

The error message is not because you're accessing a protected variable, it's because `Author` has no default constructor. If a class does not have a default constructor (a constructor with no arguments), then you must supply the necessary arguments through a `super` call in any child classes.

```
Book(String name,Author a,double price,int qtyInStock)
{
    //pass variables to parent class
    super(a.getName(), a.getEmail(), a.getGender());
    this.name=name;
    this.authorname=a.getName(); //Error
    this.price=price;
    this.qtyInStock=qtyInStock;
}
```

Comment: @Latheeshwar Raj this is the answer and you should accept it

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing several concepts. In your `Author` class you have a `protected getName()` function. This means that only `Author` classes and `Author` subclass can access it.

Further in your project you define a `Book` as *being* an `Author`. However, a `Book` is *not* an `Author` it *has* an `Author`.

Because you define your `Book` as `extends Author` the book constructor needs to call an explicit `Author` constructor. The Java compiler would call the 'default constructor' (`Author()`) if it could, but as you didn't also provide a default constructor it asks you to tell you what should be called.

My assumption is that you would rather have a structure where a `Book` has an `Author`:

```
public class Author {
  public enum Gender {
    FEMALE, MALE
  }
private final String name;
private final String email;
private final Gender gender;

public Author(String name,String email,Gender gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.gender = gender;         
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public Gender getGender() {
    return gender;
}
}

class Book  {
  private final String name;
  private final double price;
  private final int qtyInStock;
  private final Author author;

  Book(String name,Author a,double price,int qtyInStock) {
    this.name =name;
    this.author = a;
    this.price = price;
    this.qtyInStock  = qtyInStock;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public int getQtyInStock() {
    return qtyInStock;
}

  public Author getAuthor() {
     return author;
 }
}
```

For type safety I have defined `Gender` as an `enum`, instead of a `char`, which has way to may acceptable values. Also I have extended your example to make the classes ìmmutable (the `final` fields, no `set` methods). You may or may not want that.